# Azure RTOS running on one core of the CPU

Tags: windows-10, azure-rtos

A person asked a question with the following purpose at [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/463115/does-the-azure-rtos-support-intel-x64-multicore-cp.html)

> I want to use Intel Core I5 with virtualization, 2 cores for windows, another 2 cores for rtos(Azure RTOS).

I have a laptop running Windows 10 Professional with CPU Intel Core i7-8850H, it has 6 cores.

On the PC I would like to run one program in real time.

Is it possible to set the computer so that 5 cores are used for Windows 10, and 1 core is used for Azure RTOS, please?

If it is possible, may you indicate any information on how to do it, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work but it may be very difficult.
You'd have to configure Windows to use only 5 cores and isolate one core for Azure RTOS. You'd also have to configure memory for Azure RTOS. Lastly, we've never run Azure RTOS on a 64-bit Intel core, so that would be new territory.